# Accessing Parent Field through Child relationship

Tags: apex

I am running a SOQL query against the Contact object and also querying a custom child object (Job_History__c) under the Contact that has a **relationship back up to the Account object**.  My goal is to be able to output the value of a field on the Account object through the Job History object, but I get an error:

`"Variable does not exist: Account"`

I can run the same query and see the field and value I want to retrieve in the Workbench tool after turning on "Allows SOQL Parent Relationship Queries" in the Workbench settings menu, but I can't access it in Apex for some reason.  I am aware that I am trying to access the Account object through a child of the Contact object, but there is a valid reason for this for my use case.

The list of contact records **("contactList")** I am working with has a filtered subquery against the Job_History__c custom object which is also related (master-detail) to the Account.  I am trying to access the "Name" field on the Account record through this relationship, but I get the above error.

Below is the code.  How can I access the "Name" field on the Account record through the Job_History object in my for loop.

```
List<Contact> contactList = [ SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Account__r.Name FROM Job_History__r WHERE Status__c = 'Active' LIMIT 1) FROM Contact];

for (Contact con : contactList ) {
  String accountName = con.Job_History__r.Account.Name;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom object `Job_History__c` must necessarily have a *custom* relationship to the `Account` object. This means that the relationship field cannot be `Account` - it must end in `__c`/`__r`, as all custom relationships do.

Your SOQL shows that it is actually `Account__r`, which means that in Apex you would have to do

```
String accountName = con.Job_History__r[0].Account__r.Name;
```

where `0` is the index of the desired Job History within the returned list of child objects. In this case, you're querying for a maximum of one record, so you just need to check if the list is empty before you attempt this access.

Answer (score 0):

```
con.Job_History__r
```

Above will return list of job histories for a con. You need to iterate this list and get account name for each job history.

```
String accountName = con.Job_History__r[0].Account.Name;
```